# Get direct childs of the node in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

i am trying to get the direct child of parents, this is the query i have used (Scenario: File system in which a folder contains other folder)

```
MATCH (n:Folder) WHERE ID(n)=${req.query.id}
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:Folder)<-[r:CONTAINS*0..]-(n:Folder)  
return{parent:n.name,child : {name :collect(b)}}
```

but im getting all the children either direct or indirect childrens, whereas i need only the direct children

[image]

i need to get only b4,inner1, and inner2 as direct child, but im getting inner3 also using this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to get this working with this query

```
MATCH (n:Folder)-[:CONTAINS]->(childs:Folder)
WHERE id(n) = 24
RETURN childs
```

Comment: Are you getting children with this query? Looks like it's returning only the parent.

Comment: i took out a query from online and modified the direction and its giving the results, sorry for the misleading variable name